# Trace doesn't work with STM32F103C8T6 running FreeRTOS

Tags: stm32, freertos

cutting code around and playing  with STM32F103C8T6 running FreeRTOS I made simple led blink (toggle) on pin 13 inside task.

I would like to use Trace in this setup to watch on task execution.
After doing all the steps said needed to be done by [Percepio](http://percepio.com/docs/FreeRTOS/manual/Recorder.html)  and following capturing and loading data with ST-Link V2 I am unable to see any trace data.

After compilation and loading it on target, PC13 LED blink, but saving data with ST-Link utility to hex and loading into Trace only shows startup and nothing else.

Could someone please look into the code to see what could be wrong, I've tried all that I could in last several days.

[image]

This is pretty cheap board off ebay and it would be great tool to start with FreeRTOS+Trace (IMHO).

I've did blink example and will work on it further to make it skeleton for future possible FreeRTOS people.

[image]

All code is located on: https://github.com/nikola-v/FreeRTOS-Trace-Demo-STM32F103C8T6

Answer (score 0):

Is this still a problem or have you solved it already? 
Any error messages when loading the trace?
Have you checked the return value from the trace start function (uiTraceStart)?
You can also try putting a breakpoint in vTraceError, which is called if the recorder library has a problem.

You can also try putting a watch on RecorderDataPtr to see if the event counter is incremented.

If you need further assistance, feel free to contact support@percepio.com

Best Regards
Johan Kraft
Percepio AB